# Finding intersection of two planes (given in vector form) in $\mathbb C^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Say I have two non-generate planes in $ \mathbb C^3$ over $\mathbb C$, which I write as $\{s\vec x+t\vec y :s,t\in \mathbb C\}$ and $\{s\vec x_1+t\vec y_1 :s,t\in \mathbb C\}$.

If I want to find their intersection, what is a relatively efficient way of doing so?

Since I don't have Cartesian equations for these planes, I don't see how creating a system of linear equations will work, or how to use some notion of a normal vector.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** :  a vector $w$ is in the plane spanned by $u,v$ if and only if $\det \pmatrix{u \\ v \\ w} = 0$.

Comment: Ah, right. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, you're welcome !

Comment: Oops, I thought I saw how to do it, but now I'm confused. What are you saying to do?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 : If $u,v$ are fixed, the function $f(w) = \det \pmatrix{u \\ v \\ w }$ is linear, and moreover $f(w) = 0 \Leftrightarrow w \in \text{span}\{u,v\}$. So this gives you an equation for the plane spanned by $u,v$. If you have two planes spanned by some vectors, you get two equations $f(w) = 0$ and $g(w) = 0$, and solving them at the same time will give you a vector in the intersection. Is it clear ?

Comment: Isn't $f(w)$ a polynomial? I guess I don't see how I would set up solving both equations.

Comment: $f$ is an homogenous polynomial of degree $3$ if considered as function of $u,v,w$. But here, $u,v$ are fixed. So $f(w+w') = f(w) + f(w')$ for all $w,w' \in \Bbb C^3$ by usual property of the determinant. You have two linear equations to solve which admit always at least a solutions. Is this clear ?

Comment: Ok, so if I expand out the determinants $f(w)$ and $g(w)$ I'll get two linear equations in the three variables $w_1$, $w_2$ and $w_3$. Then I can solve as usual. Is there an easier way than expanding out?

Comment: Exactly. I don't think there is an easier way (but it's not that complicate), because this equation is more or less unique (more precisely, if $f(w) = 0$ and $g(w) = 0$ defines the same plane, then there is $\lambda \in \Bbb C^*$ with $f = \lambda g$. So anything will boils down to compute these determinants twice and looks for common solutions).